# Close vote review queue tag filter broken?

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

I have the close votes queue tag filter set to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) questions only. However, I still got this question in a review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3434114

[image]

I was under the impression adding that tag should only show me questions tagged with it. Is this behaviour correct?

Comment: Dumb question, but was the filter applied (the OK button clicked?)

Comment: @Undo Yes, it was. I got this review several reviews after I saved the setting.

Comment: Is it possible you ran out of questions to review with the c# tag?

Comment: @bluefeet With almost 100k questions in the queue, I'd have thought not...but c# is probably a pretty popular tag to review. Interesting thought...

Comment: @bluefeet - I believe that if you run out of questions in the queue, you get a message popping up to that effect. Of course, since I review in PHP, I've got no idea if that's actually true....

Comment: I have this twice so far one was as per @andrewsi's comment the last but the other was an audit