# Review audit honeypot messes with tags; leads to wrong comments left

Tags: bug, tags, comments, review

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920039/how-do-you-assign-a-lambda-to-a-variable-in-java-8) showed up in the close review queue for C++:

[image]

I was leaving a comment as to the inappropriateness of the `c++` tag for this question, when I went to the question and found this:

[image]

The question does not have the `c++` tag, and has never been revised.  Surely any ninja revision would be over a week old, far too old to influence the close queue filtering.

Diamond mod Oded was able to confirm that the honeypot messes with tags sometimes.

That's bad, because it messes with the quality of the question and you can no longer make a judgement about the user's reaction when you show them an alternate version of the question.  In this case I was leaving a negative comment using the review queue, and **it *did* show up on the real question!**  Of course I deleted it because I realized that it wasn't deserved, but if I was only paying enough attention to decide the question was ok (I do know enough Java for that), then I might not have visited the question.

If you're going to make a fake version of a question to show the reviewer, then review actions **including commenting** need to be disassociated from the real question.  In order to not discard useful comments, you may need to drop the facade if the reviewer tries to leave a comment, and send them to the real question to decide whether it still applies.

Related but different: [Close vote review queue tag filter broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208903/close-vote-review-queue-tag-filter-broken) (different because there the system recognized that the tag wasn't present, and passed it through the filter anyway)

Edit: Neither of the linked questions, or answers, address comments left on faked answers via the review audit system.  There's a solitary comment that mentions the issue, but nothing is resolved, since it isn't answered.  This bug report is separate from those two.

Comment: First time you got a [review audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)?

Comment: @Oded: That's what I meant by honeypot.  When I dealt with the review, though, it didn't say it was an audit.  Please un-close this, you have a real bug.

Comment: @Ben - we do sometimes add tags on review audits, in particular if the chosen audit question comes up on a filtered queue and doesn't have the requisite tag.

Comment: @Oded: Fine, I'm going to edit this question a bit to highlight what I feel is a real misfeature associated with doing this in review audit.

Comment: Confused the hell out of me the first time I saw this, too. I spent several minutes looking over the post's history and other details.

Comment: @hichris123 The commenting part seems like the most serious issue here.

Comment: @hichris123: No, that's a duplicate of the question I linked at the end of mine as "related but different".  It has *nothing to do with pretending the question has a tag it does not and never did*.  It also has nothing to do with *leaving comments on audit questions*

Comment: @BenVoigt Look at m0sa's answer: `While reviewing the faked posts appears like it matches your filters:`. Except for the commenting part... but it explains *why*, just for reference.

Comment: @hichris123: Actually: David's comment  "I was so confused by the tags that I went to the real question and almost left a snarky comment about learning to read the tag wiki excerpts when tagging a question. That could have even embarrassing :) " over there appears to be a duplicate.  But it wasn't ever properly addressed.

Comment: @BenVoigt Too bad we can't mark as duplicates of comments. :P Yeah, you're right, not really a dupe.

Comment: Thanks to all close voters for simply piling on without taking a minute to understand the issue and that neither of the linker questions resolve the issue of comments left on faked questions during audit.  In fact, I would say if this were an audit, all five of you failed.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug.

It is a test. To see if you are paying attention... which you were.

We need these, as not everyone is diligent in the pursuit of badges - robo reviewers have been and still are a problem that audits are there to help with.

---

We will sometimes add a tag to a review audit on a filtered queue - to ensure that the tag is there (and not tip our hands too early that it is an audit), as selection of a good audit question doesn't guarantee it will fit the filter.

Comment: When I dealt with the review (with `Skip`), though, it didn't say it was an audit. Please un-close this, you have a real bug.

Comment: @BenVoigt Skip does nothing with the review, so no message is ever shown.

Comment: Also, it allowed me to leave a permanent comment (which I've since deleted, when it became apparent the system lied to me) using the review interface.  That's not a good behavior for review audits!

Comment: I'd say that being able to add a comment when on the queue is a bug. If I recall correctly, comment adding when on the queue should be disabled.

Comment: @Oded they were turned off back in October, [but re-enabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-the-review-queue)

Comment: @psubsee2003 - huh. Wondering now what the consensus is... should they be on or off?

Comment: @Oded IIRC from that time, the community's opinion was they should be on, for what that's worth.  Personally, I think they ability needs to be there.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I suspect there may not be a clear consensus. The problem is that, ideally, they should be on *except* for audits... but that has some obvious issues of its own.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen or comments during audits don't pass through to the original post.  Block that from happening and you solve the problem

Comment: @psubsee2003 - or possibly, comment actions on audits will pass a known bad audit but not a known good audit.

Comment: @Oded assuming that it is possible to have a known good audit with the tags modified to fit my filter, that's going to trigger a failure for a case where the reviewer is trying to comment on the tag issue such as the OP here.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - yeah. Wasn't thinking through all the cases.

Comment: @psubsee2003: "or comments during audits don't pass through to the original post." That's pretty much guaranteed to sooner or later piss off someone who spends ten minutes composing a really good comment, only to be told that it was an audit. But even so, I still think it might be the best solution so far.

Comment: @Oded ok - have another thought - disable commenting in the close review queue and provide the optional ability to leave a comment when closing - maybe a field in the CV dialog to leave a comment.  So you don't run into this issue and still provide the needed comment functionality in the close vote queue to leave a comment as to why you are closing the post.

Comment: @psubsee2003: No, because leaving an comment is often done instead of voting to close.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I believe my question already points that out: "review actions including commenting need to be disassociated from the real question. In order to not discard useful comments, you may need to drop the facade if the reviewer tries to leave a comment, and send them to the real question to decide whether it still applies."