# Fake the filtered close reason in review audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

When presented with a close vote audit, the tag of your filter is added to the question. This is described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204645/248072).

However if you've filtered by close reason, that isn't masked:

[image]

I propose picking a choice from the current close filter when assembling the audit. When I see mismatched reasons, it's just too easy to catch, even for a robo-reviewer. And considering the tag is already masked, the precedent (and probably 80% of the code!) is already there.

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for a [lot more of this kind of confusion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223853/review-audit-honeypot-messes-with-tags-leads-to-wrong-comments-left): "What, that's *clearly* not opinion-based! Who voted for that?!" At the very least, if this is implemented, duplicates should be exempt from it. Still, it would be a lot better if they could just pick audit questions that *actually match the filter* instead of faking it.

Comment: Where did the original close reason come from? It's an audit, and a high quality post, so presumably it shouldn't be closed for *any* reason. Better to pick a filtered reason than an entirely random one. Thinking the close reason is wrong requires an accurate assessment of the question, meaning you've passed the audit correctly!

Comment: Good point on the duplicates though. I hadn't thought of that

Comment: There are both high-quality and low-quality audits. For high-quality audits, I more or less agree: the random close reason should match the filter. For low-quality audits, the system presumably uses the reason the post was actually closed for; *in principle*, it could still pick posts that match the filter, but apparently the current audit system is not set up to do that easily.

Comment: I can't remember the last low quality close audit I've seen. That said, the best solution would probably be "should this question be closed as **primarily opinion-based** or **unclear what you're asking**?"

Comment: Huh... you know, that actually makes sense.