# Close votes review does not honor the filter by tag

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

A related question: [Close vote review queue tag filter broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208903/close-vote-review-queue-tag-filter-broken)

This problem is a little different, because I receive a change in a filter rather than a question from another filter:

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to "Review-Close Votes" page
- Click on a tag that you normally don't answer
- One question from that tag will be displayed. Decide on it
- Next question will be from your default filter, not the filter that's displayed.

As you see on a screenshot, I've chosen the [mysql] tag, got one question then bam, filter got changed to [actionscript-3] which I remember being displayed to me ever since I'm determinately crawling on close votes. The displayed filter is [mysql] while it's not in effect.

**A workaround is re-applying the filter via "filter" menu.**

**UPDATE**: Once you set the filter via filter tool in close votes page, that filter will apply whenever close vote page will display a new question. So, while the workaround is still valid, the problem is narrowed to the filter request when submitting user decision on closing the given question.

Comment: [meta-tag:tag-filters] is for something else, not related to this.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I've said they are related, and in fact the bug is likely the same here and there. IMHO this question contains more info on the bug than that one, so maybe leave it open until the bug will be fixed?

Comment: Hi, I agree to keep them all open (there are 4 related I could find). I flagged it to try and get a hi-rep user to take notice and do a question merge or something useful like that. I have no rep here, so have to trust the mods will do what is best. FWIW here are some other duplicates recently http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255755/383414

Comment: Yay, the bug is fixed!