# Review filter appears to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, filtering

When browsing questions for a given tag, a review indicator has recently started showing up that links to the open review tasks for that tag.  For example, this is what I see when viewing [Python questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python):

[image]

The number `187` in the screenshot above would link to

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=python

However, clicking on that often opens review tasks that do not have the tag in question.  For example, it opened the following on successive attempts:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4853626 (c)

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4853008 (java)

It seems that the filters are broken.

A sample screenshot (note the mention of the filter on the review page):

[image]

Comment: The ElasticSearch one is an audit... not sure why the other would show up though.

Comment: I can confirm this. It is happening on a lot of occasions here too, last time I was trying to filter for close reason "opinion-based" and a question showed up that asked for "unclear what you're asking" close (and had no other close votes and was not an audit). I have a screenshot if necessary

Comment: I've been experiencing some glitches on the filters too. Like setting a tag not taking effect at once. Or not having any tag set and being filtered by tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that the front-end didn't correctly handle the query string `filter-*` parameter. After the initial review it started loading items filtered with the user's default filter settings. Fix rolled out in build rev `2014.5.22.1619`.

Comment: Does it apply to all sites, or only to SO?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it applies to all sites.. Since recently the filtered review queue links are shown on superuser too, plus the `filter-tag` and `filter-closereasons` query string parameters work on all sites - regardless if you see a link or not. They are just made more prominent on SO and SU.

Comment: All seems to be working well now.  Long live the filters!

Comment: Looks like it's broken again.

Comment: @devnull that was an audit

Comment: @m0sa Oh, sorry.  Was too quick to conclude that it's broken.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to ask the same question - the answer is "Yes, the filter by tag is broken."

I've just filtered by Android tag. The first was about Android, and the following ones in order were:

- [Find connected component for two variables in Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792202/find-connected-component-for-two-variables-in-stata) (tags: `grouping` `stata`)
- [What will public static int[] main (int[] ) return and where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798564/what-will-public-static-int-main-int-return-and-where) (tags: `java` `string` `static` `main` `args`)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791467/develop-mozilla-firefox-addon-toolbar (tags: `firefox-addon` `xul` `firefox-addon-sdk`)
- [Creating Copies In Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791044/get-variable-by-value-in-ruby) (tag: `ruby-1.8.7`)
- [Connected components in 3D image and their indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797754/connected-components-in-3d-image-and-their-indices) (tags: `c++` `c` `matlab image-processing`)

So... Broken...

---

Turns out this may be duplicate question of:

- [Close vote filter is not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255494/close-vote-filter-is-not-working?lq=1)
- [Close votes review does not honor the filter by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231909/close-votes-review-does-not-honor-the-filter-by-tag)
- [Close vote review queue tag filter broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208903/close-vote-review-queue-tag-filter-broken) (this one back in Nov 2013)